# Régiolects in France

Tags: régionalismes, france

I'm working on a school project about different régiolects in France.

I came across the word 'Bonjor' , which means 'Bonjour' in a certain régiolect but I can't seem to find which régiolect this is used in.

Does anyone have an idea which régiolect it could be?

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoproven%C3%A7al#Comparaison_dialectale) gives the word as *francoprovençal* but *francoprovençal* covers a large variety of regional languages and I've browsed quite a number of francoprovençal dictionaries before I could find one that gives *bonjor* and it appears to be in a *[Dictionnaire lyonnais-français des monts du Lyonnais](http://test.erasme.free.fr/patois/dictionnaire.htm)* (Yzeron, Rontalon).

I came upon this webpage thanks to [Lexilogos](http://www.lexilogos.com/lyonnais_dictionnaire.htm). It is a very good site as far as regional languages are concerned.

Maybe someone on this site who is from the Yzeron and Rontalon area could confirm this, but I expect that, as in most parts of metropolitan France nowadays, not many people still speak a local dialect there.

Answer (score 1):

This says Savoie: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonjor and Bresse, which is next to it.  That said, I've been in Savoie plenty and never seen/heard it, but my parisian accent would probably preclude being addressed in the local dialect :-).